# Добавление логического реверса в условие

Tags: php

Допустим есть такая функция

```
function foo($a, $b, $reverse = false) {
    if ($a > $b) return $a - $b;
    else return $a + $b;
}
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы, при `$reverse == true`, результат логической операции в условии обращался. т.е. вместо `($a > $b)` стало `!($a > $b)`. Эту операцию нужно внедрить в условие.

Comment: Оператор [XOR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E_2) - то что вы ищете

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Специально для таких случаев, как ваш, существует оператор [XOR](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E_2), известный также как *исключающее "или"*.

> результат выполнения операции является истинным тогда и только тогда,
>   когда лишь один из аргументов является истинным.

В вашем случае он применяется очень просто:

```
if ($a > $b ^ $reverse) return $a - $b;
else return $a + $b;
```

Answer (score 1):

можно воспользоваться тернарным оператором в условии

```
function foo($a, $b, $reverse = false)
{
    if ($reverse ? !($a > $b) : ($a > $b)) return $a - $b;
    else return $a + $b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Правильный ответ:

```
function foo($a, $b, $reverse = false) {
    if (($a > $b) xor $reverse) return $a - $b;
    else return $a + $b;
}
```

Спасибо [hindmost](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176878/hindmost).

Comment: можно просто приравнивать $a>$b == !$reverse
результат сравнения true либо false по этому если false = false то это true и наоборот. Так с xor получаеться если $reverse = true то оно всегда будет верное.